# how to block direct access to multiple thank you pages?

Tags: wp-redirect, template-redirect

I have multiple contact forms in my wordpress website and have a different thankyou page for each.
So, i want to prevent direct access of thankyou pages by just entering urls.
I want if the user fills the form than it is only redirected to that forms thankyou page.

I have working code for 1 thankyou page but i don't know how to set up for multiple contact forms & thankyou pages.

````
    // ID of the thank you page
    if ( ! is_page(1911)) {
        return;
    }

    // coming from the form, so all is fine
    if (wp_get_referer() == 'https://www.example.com/contact') {
        return;
    }

    // we are on thank you page
    // visitor is not coming from form
    // so redirect to home
    wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
    exit;
} );```

Other thankyou page id's: 1269, 1825, 1623
Other contact form page urls: https://www.example.com/contact-form-2, https://www.example.com/contact-form-3, https://www.example.com/contact-form-3
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by myself. I am posting the solution here in case if someone gets the same problem.

```
function wpse15677455_redirect() {
    $ref = wp_get_referer();
    if (is_page(1911) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact"){
       wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
    }
    else if(is_page(1269) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact-form-2"){
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
    }
    else if(is_page(1825) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact-form-3"){
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
    }
    else if(is_page(1623) && $ref !== "https://www.example.com/contact-form-4"){
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() ); exit();
 };
```